# pandas vertical concat not working as expected

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes which I am trying to merge/stack vertically. First dataframe has 25 columns and second dataframe has 13 columns, out of which I only want to select 1.

When I execute the code, I get more records than expected.

[image: Screenshot showing the shape of dataframes]

I dont understand where does the problem lie.

To understand this, I tried loading the data again in a fresh pandas dataframe.

```
input_df = pd.read_csv()
print(input_df.shape)
(8809, 11)
filtered_df = input_df[input_df['label'] != -1] # try to filter based on label column
print(filtered_df.shape)
(6603, 11)
```

But when I simply print the `filtered_df`, I can still see 8809 records.

[image: filtered_df]

Comment: Are you sure you want to stack one single column *vertically* to a dataframe with 25 columns, rather than just add it *horizontally*, as column #26?

Comment: in the final output, yes i need 26 columns, 25 columns from 1 df and last column from 2nd df

Comment: If you're sure the datasets match and are both in the same order, try `input_data.index = pca_df.index` before you do the concatenation.

Comment: Or simply `pca_df['input data'] = input_data.label`, assuming there is no such column yet.

Comment: thanks , the 2nd option worked. is this happening because I am not copying the original dataframe. I dont have the whole code here but i read data from csv in `df` and then do transformations before landing on to `input_data` . is that the reason behind this ? if yes, then how to ensure that my filters n transformations are actually taking place ?

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing the data, but I suspect the problem was that your two dataframes had different indexes. `pd.concat(..., axis=1)` will only put two entries in the same row if their index values match.

Comment: @Arne i have edited my question, the problem still remains unsolved i think, would highly appreciate ur input here.

Comment: When you print the `filtered_df`, you don't see 8809 records. It's just that the highest index value is still 8808. That's because the filtering just removed some rows, but did not change the index values of the remaining rows.

Comment: got it, i think the `reset_index()` is what worked for me. thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help.